# Change the wording "The moderator tag '[tag name]' must be present."

Tags: feature-request, tags, error-message, moderator-tags

When a normal user (without moderator privileges) tries to remove a moderator-only tag (e.g. [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)) from a post, this error is shown:

> The moderator tag '[tag name]' must be present.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I feel that wording is not good and can be changed to something like this:

> '[tag name]' can only be removed by moderators.

---

For reference, let's take a look at the error shown when a normal user (without moderator privileges) tries to add a moderator-only tag to a post.

> '[tag name]' can only be used by moderators.

---

I request the SE staff to change the wording of the error shown when a normal user (without moderator privileges) removes a moderator-only tag and make it consistent with the wording of the error shown when the user adds such a tag.